# Is Bitcoin mining profitable on a 8 core, 32 GB server with unused capacity?

Tags: mining-pools, mining-profitability, cpu-mining

I have a server with following specs which is using avg. 20% CPU daily :

```
Quad Core 3.20Ghz (E3-1230)
32GB RAM
1Gbps unmetered b/w
```

My questions are :

1). With today's rates does it makes sense to CPU mine Bitcoins, what results should I expect? I used http://www.coinish.com/calc/ but it does not have anything near to my hardware specs. All other answers to similar questions take the old Bitcoin rates into consideration of profitability - with 1BTC=$1200+ the scenario must have changed a lot ?

2). Secondly, can I use multiple servers and computers to work as a farm towards the common goal of mining bitcoins working as a team and will this help achieve the goal of profitability.

The servers are used for hosting websites and I pay a fixed rental. So there is no additional investment or charges involved.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Is Bitcoin mining profitable on a 8 core, 32 GB server with unused capacity?

No.

> I used http://www.coinish.com/calc/ but it does not have anything near to my hardware specs.

Expect 2-4MH per core. 38MH/s for all eight is all but useless. Maybe 80c a month, if that.

> with 1BTC=$1200+ the scenario must have changed a lot ?

No.

> Secondly, can I use multiple servers and computers to work as a farm towards the common goal of mining bitcoins working as a team and will this help achieve the goal of profitability.

No.

Comment: The last answer should be yes, no - yes, you can use multiple computers as a farm, but no, that wont help. If a computer is loosing money, more computers just loose more money.

Comment: It's really a no. The question asks if it's more profitable to have more than one mining, but it's just the same as having a sole miner. As you said, they lose at the same rate.

Comment: Actually no. It is two questions. "Can I use multiple servers and computer to work as a farm towards the common goal" - yes. "And will this help achieve the goal of profitability" - no.

Comment: The implication of the first "working as a team" is a precursor to the second, which is improving efficiency. You can see why I classed the two as one and the same, but I can also see why you treat them as different.